# List Google Drive files from a given folder on a webpage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to list all files in specific google drive folder, also which updates the list automatically, and let everyone possible to look. I've found quite amount of articles that creates a spreadsheet to list them but they don't update themselves. I just can understand bit of JavaScript of I tried to modify some of other codes to no avail. Here is what I've done.

I created a Google Apps Script file

```
function doGet(e){
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('list.html');}
```

and inside `list.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dir = "SpinFest2016 KPDS Clips"

    function listFilesInFolder(dir) {

      var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dir).next();
      var contents = folder.getFiles();
      var file;
      var name = [];
      var date = [];
      var desc = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

      file = contents[i];

      name[i] = file.getName();
      date[i] = file.getDateCreated();
      desc[i] = file.getDescription();

      };
    };
  </script>
  </head>
      <table style ="width: 100%">
      <tr>
          <th>이름</th>
          <th>제출일</th>
          <th>비고</th>
      <tr>
          <td><p id="name"></p></td>
          <td><p id="date"></p></td>
          <td><p id="desc"></p></td>
      </tr>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
      </script>

      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to list only file names first but it never worked, and I can't figure out what's wrong. If you can point me which part is wrong and what I have to do, I'd very appreciate you're help. If there's any other better way (not only google-apps-script but also other ways to display file list) that fits conditions below I'd very thankful.

- lists file names in google drive
- anyone with link can view the list
- list updates automatically (whether periodically or on any change occurs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your `doGet` gives a web browser an HTML page with some JS code embedded in it, which the browser will try to execute. And fail, since a web browser has no idea about `DriveApp`; it can run JavaScript, not Apps Script.

It's possible to [execute Apps Script code in scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#apps_script_code_in_scriptlets) embedded in a page served by `doGet`, but the syntax make take a while to get used to.

For a simple page like yours, I would just create all HTML within doGet function, and serve that. See my example.

There was one more issue with your code: `folder.getFiles()` returns a [file iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), not an array. This is something you loop over using hasNext and next methods, as shown below.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = '<table style ="width: 100%"><tr><th>name</th><th>Date</th><th>Description</th></tr>APPS_SCRIPT_CONTENT</table>';
  var dir = 'SpinFest2016 KPDS Clips';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dir).next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file, name, date, desc, list = []; 
  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    date = file.getDateCreated();
    desc = file.getDescription();
    list.push('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + date + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td></tr>');
  }
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(template.replace('APPS_SCRIPT_CONTENT', list.join('')));
  return output.setTitle('Directory List').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

This will serve up a static HTML file with the current snapshot of the directory. If the user reloads, they will get a possibly fresher copy. The file will not update on its own if the directory contents are changed; I don't think this even possible on this platform. With a scriplet running Apps Script code, one could try to update periodically, but this seems hardly practical: why waste your Apps Script execution time quota on users who opened your webpage and went for a walk?

Answer (score 1):

[`getFiles()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles) will return a [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#methods), it may not have a `.length` property. Change the loop into a while-loop and check if the iterator `hasNext` is `true`, this way it will iterate. Also, try to change how you push items in to the array. See the modified snippet, hopefully this works.

```
while (contents.hasNext()){

    file = contents.next();

    name.push(file.getName());
    date.push(file.getDateCreated());
    desc.push(file.getDescription());

};
```

What goes after this, how you display it will be up to you.